# find day and time from the mentioned total seconds starting from beginning of the week - python

Tags: python, date, time, logic

Below is the total seconds starting from beginning of the week. FYI - 86400 seconds in a day.

```
590400
```

I want to write some logic and display like SUNDAY 08:00PM using python

Comment: It's a common misconception that a day always consists of 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear *what* week you want to start on. Either pick one fixed "Monday" somewhere and go from there (as demonstrated below), or calculate *this* week's particular Monday, or whatever your logic is. **This is important should you be dealing with timezones with DST, since not every day is 86400 seconds long.**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

monday = datetime(2019, 9, 23)
ts = monday + timedelta(seconds=590400)
print(ts.strftime('%A %I:%M %p'))  # Sunday 08:00 PM
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime
t = 590400
h = 590400%86400

#calculating week
y = int(590400/86400)
if y == 6:
    print("Saturday")

res = str(int(h/3600)) + ':00'
d = datetime.strptime(res, "%H:%M")
print(d.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

Saturday
08:00 PM